# Django-cms subdomain for a particular page

Tags: django, subdomain, django-cms

I would like to have subdomain to the given page in Django-cms.
Is it possible?

For example I have page "career" and I would like to have this page available on:
career.mydomain.com.

Best regards,
Rafał

Answer (score 0):

I think the best you're going to get is a link that points to another app running on that subdomain.

Comment: Can u give me a hint how to point subdomain to app? But still i need it work in django cms.

Comment: Pages in Django CMS can point to a page within your Django app, or they can point to an absolute URL, so that's how I would point the page link to the subdomain. I was assuming that you had another Django app running on your subdomain.